# Reference to help me understand what difference in meaning a preposition creates?

Tags: learning-methods

Is there a reference (dictionary, strategy for using Google) that I can use on my own, to find an explanation of the difference between "**Prepare for** the powerpoint presentation" and "**Prepare** the powerpoint presentation"? Looking up the definition in a typical dictionary doesn't make this clear to me.

Or, is the understanding between "Prepare" vs "Prepare for" only achievable by using intuition to understand the difference, by being exposed to huge amounts of the language?

Comment: there is a difference between "to prepare something" and "to prepare for something": https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/prepare (usage 1 vs usage 2)

Comment: @flumperious aha, this Learner's Dictionary looks promising. thanks for the link